# How to check value in mysql with php pdo connection?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, pdo

I'm a totally beginner in php, so I need help with my registration script. I have 4 fields, 1 username (which is in the back transformed in an email address), 1 current email address of owner and 2 password fields. Registration is working, I only want to add the validation of username in case exists or not. My problem is that I don't know where and how to do it, should I create a function? How? I wanted to keep it simple so I didn't create any kind of session, is it possible without, as is? 
here is the code:

```
<?php

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$dbuser = 'reguser';
$dbpass = 'regpass';
$dbn = 'regform';


$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbn", $dbuser, $dbpass);


$RegScrIdErr = $RegScrIdChrErr = $OwnAddressErr = $Password1Err = $Password2Err =      $PasswordMErr = "";

$formValid = true;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
if (empty($_POST["RegScrId"])) {$RegScrIdErr = "Userame is required"; $formValid = false;}
    else {$RegScrId = check_input($_POST["RegScrId"]); 
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$RegScrId)){$RegScrIdErr = "Only letters and numbers allowed"; $formValid = false;}

             }

if (empty($_POST["OwnAddress"])) {$OwnAddressErr = "Email is required"; $formValid = false;}
    else {$OwnAddress = check_input($_POST["OwnAddress"]);
        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$OwnAddress)){$OwnAddressErr = "Invalid email format"; $formValid = false;}
 }

   if (empty($_POST["Password1"])) {$Password1Err = "Password field can't be empty!"; $formValid = false;}
  else {$Password1 = check_input($_POST["Password1"]);}
   if (empty($_POST["Password2"])){$Password2Err = "Password Confirmation can't be empty!"; $formValid = false;}
    else {$Password2 = check_input($_POST["Password2"]);
        if ($_POST["Password1"]!= $_POST["Password2"]) {$PasswordMErr = "Password does not match!"; $formValid = false;}
 }
       if ($formValid) { header('Location: index.html');  }
}




function check_input($data){
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
}




$RegScrIdFull = "$RegScrId@RegScrserver.com";  
$userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hash = hash('sha1', $Password1);

 FUNCTION createSalt(){
    $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    RETURN substr($text, 0, 3);
}
$salt = createSalt();
$PasswordSec = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);

if ($formValid) {

    $qry = $conn->PREPARE('INSERT INTO userlist (RegScrId, password, email, userIp, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $qry->EXECUTE(array($RegScrIdFull, $hash, $OwnAddress, $userIp, $salt));
    $conn = null;

}
   ?>


   <div id="wrapper">
    <header><img src="img/logo3.png" width="170" height="110" /><br><br>
    </header><br>
    <div id="section_contact">
    <form name="register"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"><br />
            <table width="850" border="0" id="tb-form">
        <tr>
                <td class="tb-form-left" colspan="2"><h4><strong>Sign Up</strong></h4><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="tb-form-left"><input type="text" name="OwnAddress" maxlength="30" placeholder=" Own Email Address" value="<?php echo $ $OwnAddress;?>" /><span class="error"><?php echo $OwnAddressErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="tb-form-left"><input type="text" class="RegScrIdPic" maxlength="28" name="RegScrId" id="email" placeholder=" RegScrserver Username" value="<?php echo $RegScrId;?>" /><span class="error"><?php echo $RegScrIdErr;?><?php echo $RegScrIdChrErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="tb-form-left"><input type="password" name="Password1" placeholder=" Enter Password"/><span class="error"><?php echo $Password1Err;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="tb-form-left"><input type="password" name="Password2" placeholder=" Confirm Password" /><span class="error"><?php echo $Password2Err;?><?php echo $PasswordMErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="tb-form-left"><input id="form-btn" type="submit" value="Create Account" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>
</div>


</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'd need to do a `select` and see if the username exists. But that's somewhat racey and could lead to a username being "sniped" out from under you if some other registration running in parallel happens to complete faster than this one.

Comment: sure I need a select, my question is how can I implemented in my script..? how can I show that user is taken next to the input field? Otherwise, parallel registration with same username, it's difficult to happen in my case, but thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want implements validation when username exist in your database you first should ask database if username really exists. Before your insert you should use SELECT query

```
$sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username');
$sth->bindValue(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
sth->execute();
while($row = $sth->fetch()){
   /// ....... here you get username
}
// if in $row you get username you can use now validation for example
if(!empty($row)){
   my_validation_function();
}
else{
  // we dont want approaching form so we redirect customer to some page
    header('location: some url');
}


if ($formValid) {


     $qry = $conn->PREPARE('INSERT INTO userlist (RegScrId, password, email, userIp, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
     $qry->EXECUTE(array($RegScrIdFull, $hash, $OwnAddress, $userIp, $salt));
     $conn = null;

 }
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer, I thought that I have to do select on my db, maybe I didn't complete the question, as you can see on my script I'm throwing the validation error messages next to the input field, I would like to do the same if user exist and not to redirect them to another page or them to lose what they inserted already..